# Jenkins Biweekly pipeline job

Tags: devops

What cron expression can I can used to schedule a Jenkins pipeline job to be run biweekly on Mondays?

I tried to find the solution but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, "pure" cron expression does not support triggering job every 2nd week. The following cron expression is relatively best option I could come up:

```
0 0 1-7,15-21,29-31 * 1
```

Jenkins seems to be able to handle it in e.g. October-22:

[image]

**My suggestion:**

- Use an option "Trigger builds remotely" from Jenkins under "Build Triggers", where you can programmatically remotely trigger Jenkins job e.g. every odd week on Monday.
- Use Jenkinsfile to configure your Jenkins job where you can add logic to trigger it e.g. every odd week on Monday.